# R: Applying a function between two dates

Tags: r, date

I have two data frames, as follows:
A data frame with trades: tradeData (sample):

```
Login   OpenTime    CloseTime   Decision
859     13/01/2014  13/01/2014  1
859     16/01/2014  16/01/2014  1
859     21/01/2014  21/01/2014  1
859     21/01/2014  21/01/2014  1
859     22/01/2014  22/01/2014  1
859     23/01/2014  23/01/2014  1
859     27/01/2014  27/01/2014  1
859     03/02/2014  03/02/2014  1
859     04/02/2014  05/02/2014  1
859     07/02/2014  07/02/2014  1
859     11/02/2014  13/02/2014  1
939     06/02/2014  28/02/2014  1
939     06/02/2014  28/02/2014  1
939     06/02/2014  28/02/2014  1
1455    03/04/2014  03/04/2014  1
1455    04/04/2014  04/04/2014  1
1455    04/04/2014  07/04/2014  1
1455    08/04/2014  08/04/2014  1
1455    08/04/2014  08/04/2014  1
1455    09/04/2014  30/04/2014  1
1455    30/04/2014  30/04/2014  1
```

and another data frame with dates: datesData (sample):

```
Login       B_A        A_B
859     22/01/2014  23/01/2014
859     03/02/2014  07/02/2014
859     11/02/2014  12/02/2014
939     06/02/2014  01/01/2200
1455    04/04/2014  08/04/2014
1455    09/05/2014  30/06/2014
```

Any trade (that would be a row in the tradeData data frame) that opens between the two dates in any row in the datesData data frame and matches the Login, should receive a 0 in the decision column. It must open on or after the date in the B_A column and open before the date in the A_B column.  This decision column is pre-populated with 1's, so all I need to do is insert the 0's

The resulting tradeData data frame would look as follows:

```
Login   OpenTime    CloseTime   Decision
859     13/01/2014  13/01/2014  1
859     16/01/2014  16/01/2014  1
859     21/01/2014  21/01/2014  1
859     21/01/2014  21/01/2014  1
859     22/01/2014  22/01/2014  0
859     23/01/2014  23/01/2014  1
859     27/01/2014  27/01/2014  1
859     03/02/2014  03/02/2014  0
859     04/02/2014  05/02/2014  0
859     07/02/2014  07/02/2014  1
859     11/02/2014  13/02/2014  0
939     06/02/2014  28/02/2014  0
939     06/02/2014  28/02/2014  0
939     06/02/2014  28/02/2014  0
1455    03/04/2014  03/04/2014  1
1455    04/04/2014  04/04/2014  0
1455    04/04/2014  07/04/2014  0
1455    08/04/2014  08/04/2014  1
1455    08/04/2014  08/04/2014  1
1455    09/04/2014  30/04/2014  0
1455    30/04/2014  30/04/2014  1
```

So, for example, the fifth row in the tradeData data frame opens on 22/01/2014 and before 23/01/2014 (the first row in the datesDate data frame) and matches the login in that row, so it receives a 0.

Any help would be awesome! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: can I suggest to post your data using `?dput`

Comment: @RockScience, to do that do I just type `dput` into the console and copy paste the results?

Comment: Hi Mike, my comment above my answer for clarification.

Comment: @akrun, I'm struggling with the `foverlaps` function. Here is what I've done so far: `colnames(datesData)[c(2:3)] = c("OpenTime","CloseTime")`/
`setkey(datesData,"B_A","A_B")`. 
`foverlaps(tradeData,datesData,by.tradeData = c("OpenTime","Closetime"),by.transferDates = c("OpenTime","CloseTime"))`
However, I it isn't working and I'm not sure how to fix it?

Comment: @Mike I will check it later as I have to go now.

Comment: @Mike yes exactly, otherwise we cannot use your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an etc. solution using the `sqldf` package.

```
tradeData$OpenTime <- as.Date(trade.data$OpenTime, format="%d/%m/%Y")
datesData$B_A <- as.Date(datasData$B_A, format="%d/%m/%Y")
datesData$A_B <- as.Date(datasData$A_B, format="%d/%m/%Y")

sqldf(c("UPDATE tradeData
      SET Decision = 0
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM datesData WHERE
                      tradeData.Login = datesData.Login AND
                      tradeData.OpenTime >= datesData.B_A  AND
                      tradeData.OpenTime < datesData.A_B)",
      "SELECT * FROM tradeData"))

#    Login   OpenTime  CloseTime Decision
# 1    859 2014-01-13 13/01/2014        1
# 2    859 2014-01-16 16/01/2014        1
# 3    859 2014-01-21 21/01/2014        1
# 4    859 2014-01-21 21/01/2014        1
# 5    859 2014-01-22 22/01/2014        0
# 6    859 2014-01-23 23/01/2014        1
# 7    859 2014-01-27 27/01/2014        1
# 8    859 2014-02-03 03/02/2014        0
# 9    859 2014-02-04 05/02/2014        0
# 10   859 2014-02-07 07/02/2014        1
# 11   859 2014-02-11 13/02/2014        0
# 12   939 2014-02-06 28/02/2014        0
# 13   939 2014-02-06 28/02/2014        0
# 14   939 2014-02-06 28/02/2014        0
# 15  1455 2014-04-03 03/04/2014        1
# 16  1455 2014-04-04 04/04/2014        0
# 17  1455 2014-04-04 07/04/2014        0
# 18  1455 2014-04-08 08/04/2014        1
# 19  1455 2014-04-08 08/04/2014        1
# 20  1455 2014-04-09 30/04/2014        1
# 21  1455 2014-04-30 30/04/2014        1
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to dates usefull columns
setDT(tradeData)
setkey(tradeData, Login)
tradeData[,OpenTime:=as.Date(OpenTime, format="%d/%m/%Y")]

# convert to dates usefull columns
df1 = datesData 
df1$B_A = as.Date(df1$B_A, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df1$A_B = as.Date(df1$A_B, format="%d/%m/%Y")

tradeData[,Decision:=sapply(OpenTime,function(d){ 
                          dt=df1[df1$Login==Login,]
                          as.integer(!any(d>=dt$B_A & d<dt$A_B))
                  }),
      by=Login]
```

Result look like this:

```
> tradeData
    Login   OpenTime  CloseTime Decision
 1:   859 2014-01-13 13/01/2014        1
 2:   859 2014-01-16 16/01/2014        1
 3:   859 2014-01-21 21/01/2014        1
 4:   859 2014-01-21 21/01/2014        1
 5:   859 2014-01-22 22/01/2014        0
 6:   859 2014-01-23 23/01/2014        1
 7:   859 2014-01-27 27/01/2014        1
 8:   859 2014-02-03 03/02/2014        0
 9:   859 2014-02-04 05/02/2014        0
10:   859 2014-02-07 07/02/2014        1
11:   859 2014-02-11 13/02/2014        0
12:   939 2014-02-06 28/02/2014        0
13:   939 2014-02-06 28/02/2014        0
14:   939 2014-02-06 28/02/2014        0
15:  1455 2014-04-03 03/04/2014        1
16:  1455 2014-04-04 04/04/2014        0
17:  1455 2014-04-04 07/04/2014        0
18:  1455 2014-04-08 08/04/2014        1
19:  1455 2014-04-08 08/04/2014        1
20:  1455 2014-04-09 30/04/2014        1
21:  1455 2014-04-30 30/04/2014        1
```

Comment: It depends how you interpret the author condition which is a little bit unclear (is it a comparison row per row, as he wrote, or over all rows - eg one date can be superior to B_A in a certain row and inferior to A_B in another, different,row).

Comment: ok, deleted my comment before you posted yours, shouldn't the close time column be used to check that open time is > than B_A and close time is < A_B?

Comment: Ïf you read correctly the closeTime column is never mentionned :)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel  
Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tried it on a subset of my data and it appears to work perfectly. However, my dataset is over 5 million rows, and it takes a very long time (its been running for 20 minutes and still isn't finished). Is there anything I could do to speed it up? Thanks again!

Comment: is your data.frame datesData huge? In that case, it's good to convert it as well in data.table.

Comment: Its about 180 000 rows, yes. Ok, I'll convert that too, but I suspect it might still be very slow